# Merging string Date and int Hour in timestamp in python pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series

I am trying to forecast future values using Prophet. The forecast is quite accurate but the data preprocessing part takes quite some time because I don't know how to deal with the following problem:

Given the columns:

```
Date - of type object in the same format as the example: 2019-01-01 
      00:00:00 ( So note that they all have 00:00:00 even though the hour 
      associated to the specific row may not be 0)


Hour - of type int in the range [0,23]
```

I would like to create a new column named let's say Time containing both the Date and the associated hour. So if I have a row with

Date = 2019-01-01 00:00:00 and Hour = 13

I would like the corresponding Time column to contain the value 2019-01-01 13:00:00. I would then drop the Date and Hour columns because I don't need them anymore.

I've succeeded in doing this using the code below but it is very inefficient since for 2000 entries it takes around 2 minutes and my entire dataset actually contains millions of instances.

Could you please suggest better alternatives to this approach that are very fast?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
data = df_all.loc[df_all['Cell_Id']==top_cells[0]]
data['Time'] = 0

for i in range(len(data)):
    data['Time'].iloc[i] = pd.to_datetime(str(data['Date'].iloc[i])[:10].replace('-',"")+str(data['Hour'].iloc[i]), format = '%Y%m%d%H')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-01-01','2019-01-02'],
                     'Hour':[4,5]})

data['Datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(data.pop('Date')) + 
                    pd.to_timedelta(data.pop('Hour'), unit='h'))
print (data)
             Datetime
0 2019-01-01 04:00:00
1 2019-01-02 05:00:00
```